# micropython Simple pin input does not work (raspberry pi pico)

Tags: micropython

Does anybody know why the button2 work but the button1 does not

Button2 is connectet with GP14 and ground
Button1 is connectet with GP15 and ground

Button1 is always High

```
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

motorRight = Pin(18, Pin.OUT)
motorLeft = Pin(16, Pin.OUT)

button1 = Pin(15, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
button2 = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)

while True:
    if not button1.value():
        motorLeft.value(0)
        motorRight.value(1)
        print(button1.value(), "BTN: 1")
        sleep(0.1)
        
    if not button2.value():
        motorRight.value(0)
        motorLeft.value(1)
        print(button2.value(), "BTN: 2")
        sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: perhaps button 1 is fried. Why not try button 3?

Comment: thanks I tried other pins and it worked :)

Comment: #Goran Nikolic, How nice to hear the good news from you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There were some issues with GP15 on earlier Micropython Pico builds. That should now have been fixed. You could try another pin or try the latest firmware (1.14 is current as of the time of this post) and see.

Comment: What is your source?